# Separate output from different threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

All my code is writing log via *say()* to *sys.stderr* and error redirect. In a multithreaded server I want each thread to write to a separate log file. Can I accomplish this without rewriting all code used by threads?

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def say(*args):
    print(*args, file=sys.stderr)

def worker(num):
    for _ in range(5):
        say("worker", num, "working")
        sleep(.1)

for num in range(4):
    Thread(target=worker, args=(num,)).start()
```

Output is mixed in, the goal is to redirect it to a differnt log file for each thread:

```
worker 0 working
worker 1 working
worker 2 working
worker 3 working
worker 0 working
worker 1 working
worker 3 working
worker 2 working
. . .
```

My understanding is that if I try to redirect stderr to a file inside thread the redirection will be shared by all threads:

```
def worker(num):
    sys.stderr = open('worker{}.log'.format(num), 'w')
    for _ in range(5):
        say("worker", num, "working")
```

Result as expected:

```
$ cat worker3.log
worker 1 working
worker 1 working
worker 1 working
worker 3 working
worker 3 working
worker 3 working
worker 3 working
worker 3 working
```

---

## Updates

@Amber, I already have a unique identifier and can use it as a thread name:

```
def say(*args, end='\n'):
    print(currentThread().getName(), *args, file=sys.stderr, end=end)
    sys.stderr.flush()

t_worker = Thread(name=str(num), target=worker, args=(num,))
```

I cannot dynamically choose logfile for each thread because *say()* is global -- would need to either put a semaphore on this global log file storage, or pass a logging object to every single function that logs progress.

Comment: @Amber, I already have a unique identified and can use it as a thread name:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use thread local storage (via the `threading.local` class) to store a separate file object for each thread. The `say` function could then look up the right file:

```
local = threading.local()

def say(*args):
    if not hasattr(local, "logfile"):
        local.logfile = open("logfile{}".format(threading.get_ident()), "a")

    print(*args, file=local.logfile)
```

I'm using `threading.get_ident` to get a hopefully unique value to generate a log file name. If there's a more logical way to name the files in your program, I'd suggest you use it instead. You might even want to separate out the creation of the file from the `say` function. For instance, you could make it part of the thread's startup code:

```
local = threading.local()

def say(*args):
    print(*args, filename=local.logfile)

def worker1():
    local.logfile = open("logfile_worker1", "a")

    # do stuff here, including calling `say()` as necessary
```

Comment: muchas gracias , señor

Answer (score 0):

You could call [`threading.get_ident()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_ident) in your `say()` function to decide where to write the line. It's not perfect (since thread ID numbers are allowed to be reused after a thread ends and another is created), but if your threads are long-running then it might work for your purposes.